# Shift dataframe columns to find the longest possible row of same value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to write a pattern searching function but got stuck on the following:

What would be the best way to shift all columns in a dataframe (in either direction, and/or by any amount of rows), to try and generate a single row with the most possible occurances of the same value (`True` in this case), with the least amount of moves?

For instance,

```
seqs = ['GCAATTACTCGCCGTA', 'CTACAATGCTAGCATG']
conv_dict = {
    'A': 1,
    'T': 2,
    'G': 3,
    'C': 4 
}

search_pattern = 'CAAT'
search_pattern_arr = [conv_dict[n] for n in search_pattern]

_ = []
for s in seqs:
    _.append([conv_dict[n] for n in s])

df = pd.DataFrame(_, dtype=np.int64)
display(df)
```

[image]

```
_ = pd.DataFrame(dtype=np.int64)

for i, n in enumerate(search_pattern_arr):
    _[i] = df.T[0].eq(n)
display(_)
```

[image]

```
_[1] = _[1].shift(-1)
_[2] = _[2].shift(-2)
_[3] = _[3].shift(-3)
```

[image]

Row 1 in the final image being an example of what I need.

I can write a tedious for loop with iters and enumerators to get the result, but was wondering if there exists an easy `numpy` or `pandas` option?

Comment: is the image your desired output? or do you need `1` as the output?

Comment: the image is the desired output. So row 1 would be what I'm looking for. all values in row 1 are True, and it only took 3 shifts to get to that desired output